# Puppet Augeas - cannot update value in xml node containing CDATA

Tags: xml, puppet, augeas

I have an xml document similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<example>
    <member name="dbsettings">
        <node name="username"><![CDATA[someusername]]></node>
        <node name="password"><![CDATA[mypassword]]></node>
    </member>
    <member name="sitesettings">
        <node name="title"><![CDATA[just a title]]></node>
    </member>
</example>
```

And I'm trying to update these settings in puppet using the following augeas command:

```
set example/member[#attributes/name='dbsettings']/node[#attributes/name='username']/#text anotherusername
```

What I expect it to do is to replace the entire contents of the node by "anotherusername" instead it just appends it resulting in:

```
<node name="username"><![CDATA[someusername]]>anotherusername</node>
```

How can I select and update the contents of the CDATA element using augeas or remove it without removing the actual node itself? (the real node contains more attributes which I don't want to hard-code in)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Augtool can show you what the tree looks like actually:

```
$ augtool -At "Xml incl /test.xml" -r .
augtool> set /augeas/context /files/test.xml
augtool> print example/member[#attribute/name='dbsettings']/node[#attribute/name='username']
/files/test.xml/example/member[1]/node[1]
/files/test.xml/example/member[1]/node[1]/#attribute
/files/test.xml/example/member[1]/node[1]/#attribute/name = "username"
/files/test.xml/example/member[1]/node[1]/#CDATA = "someusername"
```

This shows two things:

- The syntax for attributes is `#attribute`, without a 's'
- The CDATA is stored in a `#CDATA` subnode

Hence your command should be:

```
set example/member[#attribute/name='dbsettings']/node[#attribute/name='username']/#CDATA anotherusername
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I couldn't find information about the #CDATA subnode anywhere and the augtool wasn't showing a tree for me